# problems in useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, addeventlistener, use-effect

Let's say I have a state called *count*.

```
const [count, setCount] = useState();
```

Now let's say I would like to increase *count* with 1 every time some key in the keyboard is being pressed.
So I can use useEffect hook and add an event listener to it.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", increaseCount);
 }, []);
```

The function increaseCount, increasing *count* with 1

```
 const increaseCount = () => {
     setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
};
```

Well everything is working great. **BUT,** if I want to get the current value of *count* inside increaseCount, I can't do this! The event listener is only called once when the component is mounting (because the useEffect has an empty dependency array).

And if I add *count* to the dependency array, I have a new problem - I'm creating a kind of loop, because useEffect will call increaseCount, that will call setCount(), that will cause the component to re-render, which will call useEffect again and so on and so on.

I have this kind of problem on a few projects I'm currently working on, and it is very frustrating. So if you know how to answer this - thanks! :)

## snippets

When using an empty dependency array and login count inside increaseCount, *count* will always be 0:

```js
// Get a hook function
    const {useState, useEffect} = React;

    const Counter = () => {
      const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", increaseCount);
  }, []);

  const increaseCount = () => {
    setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
    console.log(count);
  };

      return (
        <div>
          count = {count}
        </div>
      );
    };

    // Render it
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Counter />,
      document.getElementById("react")
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <div id="react"></div>
```

and when adding *count* to the dependency array, we see this "loop" thing happening:

```js
// Get a hook function
    const {useState, useEffect} = React;

    const Counter = () => {
      const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", increaseCount);
  }, [count]);

  const increaseCount = () => {
    setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
    console.log(count);
  };

      return (
        <div>
          count = {count}
        </div>
      );
    };

    // Render it
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Counter />,
      document.getElementById("react")
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Will you please provide a complete code snippet? It is not possible to figure out what is wrong given the code you have provided.

Comment: @JustinTaddei I added snippets

Comment: @Ori I can easily give instruction on what's happening (stale closure), and ways to work around it, but the real issue is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Why are you trying to use the state in the same function as the `useEffect` instead of just using a secondary effect to work with the updated count?

Comment: @ZacharyHaber well, I have more then one situation that I am trying to do so. I will try to explain one of them shorty: I have a function that add a character that pressed on the keyboard to an array,  it setting the values of 2 states: the array itself, and the current index. I want that every time the user clicking some a-z key in the keyboard, it will add the character to the array.

Comment: maybe useCallback will help me?

Comment: You don't need to re-run the useEffect() because `addEventListener("keydown", increaseCount)` is just plumbing. As an analogy, you don't have to renew your pipes every time you want to take a shower. In fact it would be very bad to set up a new event listener on every render. And you should remove the listener on component removal.

Comment: WRT to a function like `increaseCount`, *anything* used inside that is not passed in as a parameter will have the same initial value. Use of any closure variable like `count` requires a `useCallback()` with `count` in the dependency array.

Comment: @SuchAnIgnorantThingToDo-UKR can you explain this in more details please?

Comment: What don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

What you *should* do really depends on what you *need* to do. See [X Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

As mentioned there are multiple use cases you are trying for.

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useMemo, Fragment } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  function increaseCount(ev) {
    setCount((count) => {
      const newCount = count + 1;
      // You can use the newCount here for something basic if needed...
      console.log(newCount);
      // I'm not positive, but I'm farily sure that setting other state
      // from within a set state function might be problematic.
      // If you feel the need to do something with side effects here,
      // Consider another useEffect as below.
      return newCount;
    });
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", increaseCount);
    // Always clean up after your effect!
    return () => document.removeEventListener("keydown", increaseCount);
    // If you use `increaseCount` here as a dependency (which you should), the function will get recreated every time.
    // Or you could set it up by creating the `increase count function inside the effect itself
  }, [increaseCount]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // If you need to use newCount for something more complicated, do it here...
   // Or for side effects
  }, [count]);

  const arrayCountSized = useMemo(() => {
    // You can use the count here in a useMemo for things that are
    // derived, but not stateful in-of-themselves
    return new Array(count).fill(null).map((_, idx) => idx);
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>{count}</div>
      <ul>
        {arrayCountSized.map((row) => (
          <li key={row}>{row}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"/>
```

---

As for the situation you mentioned in particular, here's one solution.

You can get the "current Index" from the array length normally, which is what I'm doing here.

If the "currentIndex" is more complicated than that and inexorably tied together with the array state, you should `useReducer` to set up that tied state in a pure fashion.

You could also use a reference to the array in your listener function.

```
const arrayRef = useRef(array);
useEffect(()=>{arrayRef.current=array},[array]);
// arrayRef.current is safe to use in any effect after this.
```

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useMemo, Fragment } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [array, setArray] = useState([]);
  const curIndex = array.length - 1;
  useEffect(() => {
    function addKey(ev) {
      if (ev.key.length === 1 && ev.key >= "a" && ev.key <= "z") {
        setArray((arr) => [...arr, ev.key]);
      }
    }
    document.addEventListener("keydown", addKey);
    // Always clean up after your effect!
    return () => document.removeEventListener("keydown", addKey);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>Current Index: {curIndex}</div>
      <div>Keys pressed: </div>
      <ul>
        {array.map((row, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{row}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"/>
```

---

## useReducer Approach:

As I don't have enough details, this is the same solution as above, just in a reducer.

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useReducer, useMemo, Fragment } = React;

function reducer(state, key) {
  if (!key) {
    return state;
  }
  const array = [...state.array, key];
  return { array, currentIndex: array.length - 1 };
}

const App = () => {
  const [{ array, currentIndex }, addKey] = useReducer(reducer, {
    array: [],
    currentIndex: -1,
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    function keydownListener(ev) {
      if (ev.key.length === 1 && ev.key >= "a" && ev.key <= "z") {
        addKey(ev.key);
      }
    }
    document.addEventListener("keydown", keydownListener);
    // Always clean up after your effect!
    return () => document.removeEventListener("keydown", keydownListener);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>Current Index: {currentIndex}</div>
      <div>Keys pressed: </div>
      <ul>
        {array.map((row, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{row}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"/>
```